# A nil pointer panic occurs only in debug mode while calling fmt.Sprintf

Tags: go, goland, delve

### What version of Go are you using (go version)?

```
$ go version
go version go1.18 darwin/amd64
```

### What did you do?

I wrote some simple code below that it try to print a struct

```golang
import v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
import metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"

func main() {
    data := v1.Namespace{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            DeletionTimestamp: nil,
        },
    }
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%#v", data)
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

### What did you expect to see?

same behavior with or without debugger

### What did you see instead?

I was intended to print a struct called Namespace which is defined in k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go, when I run it simply in GoLand(GoLand 2021.3.4) without debug, it runs as expected and the structure of the object had been printed in the console, but when i run it also in Goland but with debug, the program had been interrupted by an error: "bad access: nil dereference". the call stack is:

```
<autogenerated>:2
fmt.(*pp).handleMethods (print.go:603) fmt
fmt.(*pp).printValue (print.go:723) fmt
fmt.(*pp).printValue (print.go:806) fmt
fmt.(*pp).printValue (print.go:806) fmt
fmt.(*pp).printArg (print.go:712) fmt
fmt.(*pp).doPrintf (print.go:1026) fmt
fmt.Sprintf (print.go:219) fmt
main.main (main.go:97) main
runtime.main (proc.go:250) runtime
runtime.goexit (asm_amd64.s:1571) runtime
 - Async Stack Trace
<autogenerated>:2
```

this is a little bit weird: If this(panic) is a intented behavior, then how can it runs correctly without debugger?

Comment: How are you debugging? Did you put any breakpoint?

Comment: I was debugging it by Goland Run -> Debug and without any breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried to upgrade the mac os version, but it did not work.

The main reason is debugserver version，mine before version is:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/Resources/debugserver --version
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1205.0.27
```

and, later upgrade debugserver by:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and it will remain to intall again, and the latest version is:

```
debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:LLDB  PROJECT:lldb-1316.0.9.46
```

then, everything works.

Comment: thank you! and btw, where did you find the solution?